# How to display results from bulk actions on a filtered list, where the action renders the item(s) outside of the filter scope

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

I am trying to implement bulk action updates on a filtered list of items.

The filters include groups, categories, assignees, reviewers, and unassigned. Filters are AND logical. Bulk actions update these parameters on multiple items.

Now the question is, performing a bulk action could render an item outside the scope of the filter. This currently causes the item to be removed from the list.

Is letting the item fall out of the list good UX? Any other thoughts?

Here is a rough mockup for reference:

[image]

Comment: These seems like a particularly dense and complex UI and question. You've provided a lot of explanatory text, but it doesn't help pinpoint your issue. This takes a lot of time and attention to understand and solve, and when this is the case, you're less likely to receive quality attention. I recommend using the built in wireframing tool to mockup the relevant parts of the UI (so it's easier to see and understand than your sketch) and using more markup and annotations than the single label you have now.

Comment: To the 'close' voter: there's a potentially valuable q/a about bulk actions here. Consider prompting the asker to improve the quality of their question before closing for the reason 'unclear what you're asking'.

Comment: (I'm not the close voter, but) This is a repost of an earlier question that was closed, albeit a bit more the point. I think I grasp the fundamental problem here, but I'm not confident enough to make serious edits that this question requires. "How to display results from bulk actions on a filtered list, where the action renders the item(s) outside of the filter scope". @Swapnali, is this accurate?

Comment: @Alan Yes,the question you have given in above comment is correct.     "How to display results from bulk actions on a filtered list, where the action renders the item(s) outside of the filter scope"                                                               I am Looking for UX on same condition, By updating filtered list, User should not get confused.

Comment: @SwapnaliHadawale Great! I made lots of edits to your question to focus it more for this site. If I wrote anything incorrectly please use the "edit" button.

Comment: Isn't the usual course of action, when an action can have unintended consequences, simply to warn the user of those consequences? If the user clicks to bulk update and some items will be removed, just give them a pop up warning that that will happen. If reasonable to so, include a summary of actual items. 

'Your current filter settings mean that the following items will not be updated:

- Item 2
- Item 5
- Item 11

Comment: This is what Excel does, and it only sometimes surprises me. @Alan Good job on the editing!

Answer (score 1):

**Rearticulating the problem statement**

You have a list view with filtering option A and B of an attribute. You filter for option A and select a few rows from the results table. Now if you change their assignment from option A to B then what should happen?

Should you show the rows even if they are not meeting the filtering criteria or hide it?

Feel free to add if I missed any point.

**Suggestion**

If in your flow once a bulk change is done, users have no compelling reason to revisit those rows then you can hide the rows and maintain the filters.

Another approach could be to reset the filters once the bulk action is taken assuming filtering is done for bulk actions only and only one bulk action at a time is the majority use case.

Look into your primary flows, what are the tasks you are optimising for and what will break. Consider them and do the trade-offs.

Goodluck.